# Why does nothing shows in my pycharm terminal when I run my Odoo Dev?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm having a trouble in my odoo development right now because after changing some part, my terminal doesn't show anything when I run my `odoo config`. My models shows when I re-run the program, but when I edit `xml` files, I don't know if i have an error or anything because no message is being shown.

I've been following tutorials in internet but it doesn't work.

so this is what it shows when I run`odoo-bin configuration`, I've got an empty terminal, and it works when I search `localhost:8069` but the problem is, I don't know what are the error messages

[image]

My configuration is like this.

[image]

And this is my directory

[image]

I use `venv` for installing dependecies for the odoo development stored in requirements.txt`

my python interpreter's path is `c:\Odoo\odoo16\venv\Scripts\python.exe`

**EDIT**

Hello, updates, I think i got the problem but I don't know how can I configure it, how can i show the odoo.log in my terminal?

Comment: had you added port in config (8069 or any)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I got a workaround for this.
In the Odoo conf file uncomment the logfile value like:

```
logfile = C:\Program Files\Odoo 17.0.20240220\server\odoo.log
```

After that in Pycharm go to configuration and under **Modify Options** select **Specify logs to be shown in console** option.

[Pycharm Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNwyj.png)

After that specify the file path in Logs setting as you can see in above screenshot. Now when you run the odoo service you will notice a separate console showing the log in live view (you have to select info/all in filter option otherwise it is selected to error by default).

[Logs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paoJi.png)

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was leaving the logfile= field in odoo.conf empty.

example:

logfile =